# How to check 2 checkboxes that have the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, forms

So I have a ajax search form which gives results with a checkbox:
Here is part of PHP code for each search result:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="lovkrav_checkbox checkbox_search" name="lovkrav['.$lovkrav_id.']" value="'.$lovkrav_id.'" orig-id="lovkrav'.$lovkrav_id.'" id="lovkravs'.$lovkrav_id.'" '.$checked.'/>
```

and there is a twin checkbox already on website with the same name but with different id. 
By using "**orig-id**" property I am getting the id of the twin checkbox. Both checkboxes have same class **lovkrav_checkbox**.

I came to the point where the click event is detected by the twin checkbox as it should but not the checkbox you clicked on! 
Here is the code:

```
 $(document).on("click",".lovkrav_checkbox",function(e){
    toggle_id = document.getElementById($(this).attr("orig-id"));        
    $(toggle_id).trigger("click");
});
```

What I want to achieve is when a user clicks on one checkbox - the twin checkbox (the one with same name property) will be checked/unchecked as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to do, please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: What I want to achieve is when a user clicks on one checkbox - the twin checkbox (the one with same name property) will be checked/unchecked as well.

Comment: @trojan The pitfall here is if your page loads up with one of the checkboxes checked.. is that a possible situation? in that case you'd want every click to check the unchecked and unchecked the checked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would be easier to toggle the checked state with vanilla javascript.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test">
<input type="checkbox" name="test">
```

**JS**

```
//All of the checkboxes
var $checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox][name=test]");

//The event handler
$checkboxes.on("click", function() {
    //Get the state of the check box you clicked
    var checkedState = this.checked

    //Make it the state of all the checkboxes
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        this.checked = checkedState;
    });
});
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NVg2Z/)

Comment: I am getting this error: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=checkbox][name=lovkrav[621]]

Comment: I got it!, had to escape the name in quotas:   var $checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox][name=\'"+$(this).attr(\'name\')+"\']");

Comment: You may want to change the $checkboxes selector to something a little more specific in production. Maybe try `.lovkrav_checkbox[name=\'"+$(this).attr(\'name\')+"\']`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zjV8N/2/)

```
 $(document).on("click",".check",function(e){
    $("."+this.className).prop("checked", this.checked);
 });
```

Comment: this won't do since it toggles all checkboxes with the same class

Answer (score 1):

Try this too:

js:

```
 $(document).on("click",".lovkrav_checkbox",function(e){
    toggle_id = $(this).attr("name");
     isChecked = $(this).prop("checked");
     $("input:checkbox").each(
         function(){

             if($(this).attr("name") == toggle_id && isChecked){
                 $(this).prop("checked",true);
             }
             else{
                 $(this).prop("checked",false);
             }
         });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wq5Un/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[type=checkbox][name=test]").prop("checked",true);
```